# Problem with concurrent sessions and OAuth2 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm working with Spring Security 5.6.0 and OAuth 2.0 authentication. I'm trying to limit the concurrent sessions for each user to one. After some tries, I managed to write this code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http
  [...]
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .invalidSessionUrl("/expired")
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

with

```java
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    return sessionRegistry;
}

@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

Yet, this doesn't work for some reason, letting two different browsers make API calls with the same user logged in. Any suggestions?

Comment: 2 Different browser means 2 different sessions. If you want to avoid same user to login again while first is logged in, you need to maintain the a session cache/db of currently logged in users and check against it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But if so, what is the purpose of maximumSessions? I mean, if I try re-logging in in the same browser with a different tab, I simply get logged in in another tab automatically. Isn't maximumSession a parameter to avoid concurrent logins on different sessions (so, different browsers)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mao95 You are logging in to your authorization server, that doesn't know if you are already logged in to your client. You could restrict the login to your own authorization server.

Comment: @dur now that you made me think about it, it makes sense. Unfortunately I must login in an external authorization server, without restricting the login to my own server. Is there a way to check for maximumSession also in this way? Maybe adding a table to the db with the currently logged in users and check against it, or do you have a better idea?

Comment: @mao95 I'm sure there is a way to do that, but I can't give you any details, I would need to look into the documentation and code of Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

When oauth application deployed with multiple replicas(instances) and session are stored in redis etc., SessionRegistryImpl is not sufficient , use SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry it allows concurrent session management with Spring Security in a clustered environment.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/security/SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry.html

```
       @Inject
       @Named("redisConnectionFactory")
       private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

       @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
       @Bean
       public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry()
       {
          return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(sessionRedisOperations()));
         
       }
    
       @Bean
       public RedisOperations<Object, Object> sessionRedisOperations()
       {
          RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
          redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
          redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
          redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
          redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
          return redisTemplate;
       }
         @Override
          public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
          {
              http
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(maximumSessions)
                .expiredUrl(("/login?ex=MultiSession"))
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
        ....
        }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 1800, redisFlushMode = RedisFlushMode.IMMEDIATE)
    public class RedisConfig
    {
    
     @Bean
       public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory()
       {
          LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = getLettuceClientConfiguration();
    
      ....
      }
 }
```